# Highstock Options in Yii Booster Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, yii-booster

Is it possible to use Highstock Options in Yii-Booster Highcharts extension? I've tried to set up rangeSelector property, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rangeselector is available only in highstock.js, so if Yii uses only highcharts, rangeselector cannot be used.